# GRUB menu not adding windows partition

Tags: grub2, windows-10, 19.04

I had 2 SSDs installed on my machine.I had installed both OS on my 2nd SSD. At that time everything boot ok from my `grub` menu. But once, I removed first SSD, my `grub` menu broke, nothing booted. After applying `boot-repair` with live USB drive now I only can find `ubuntu` on my grub menu.

My `sudo os-prober` command showing my windows partition:

```
user@hp-elitebook-8470p:~$ sudo os-prober
[sudo] password for user: 
/dev/sda1:Windows 10:Windows:chain
```

But running `sudo update-grub` not adding my partition into `GRUB` menu at startup.
I had tried `boot-repair`. But, it didn't work. I can also see my win partion in `gparted` marked `boot`.  [image: gparted-screenshot]

I had tried this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/217970/318808) from [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) and rebooted and `GRUB` menu is unchanged.
`grub-customizer` screenshot:
[image: grub-customizer-screenshot]
Anything I am missing?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your Windows partition is flagged with “boot” which makes me think it’s a legacy install. Have you updated this from Windows 7 over the years? You have a small ext4 partition which probably is involved in the Ubuntu boot process. If so I don’t think that partition can boot Windows

Comment: You should run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If it does not solve your problem automatically, please [edit] your question to include the Boot-Info URL generated by Boot-Repair. And why are you tagging your question [tag:19.04]? Are you really using [this EOL version](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-January/000253.html)?

Comment: @Melebius: It appears my system bios setting is setup for `legacy` mode and not `UEFI`. Attempting changing it giving me a warning. Unfortunately I have no bootable usb flash drive with me and and wont be able to purchase one till next sunday. I rather not change my BIOS to UEFI. So, can my win partition be booted in BIOS mode from grub menu along with ubuntu? Or is it that I cannot have multiboot without `UEFI`?

Comment: I think now I know what went wrong during my last `boot-repair` run. Gotta try `boot-repair` again with system bios set for `UEFI` mode

Comment: GRUB is used for multiboot on legacy BIOS, too, but all the OSes must use the same boot type (legacy/UEFI). However, I doubt your Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode as you have no UEFI partition (`/boot/efi`). And you cannot easily convert your legacy-BIOS Windows installation to UEFI as far as I know. _“Gotta try boot-repair again with system bios set for UEFI mode”_ Don’t do this blindly! Rather just post your Boot-Info URL generated by Boot-Repair.

Comment: @Melebius: Done. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ttCWXVHtDn/

Comment: Thanks. Your GRUB configuration contains some manually added UEFI-related Windows items which I find wrong (see my previous comment). The recommended repair is to “purge (in order to fix customized files) and reinstall the grub2 of sda3” and I think this could help. You could also backup and manually remove the file `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` and run `sudo update-grub` which might help, too.

Comment: Windows 10 in BIOS boot mode, is not dual boot friendly. Grub only boots working Windows and that means Windows fast start up must be off as it sets hibernation flag. Then os-prober also cannot find Windows. Windows keeps adding fast boot back in with updates which you may not even see. With UEFI, you just boot Windows & turn off fast start up. But with BIOS and one drive, you have to temporarily reinstall Windows boot loader, fix Windows & then restore grub. Always have Windows repair flash drive & Ubuntu live installer flash drive handy.

Comment: Win 10 apearing on my GRUB menu now. But selecting win10, restarting my whole system. Also, can't delete hibernation files from my win drive. Can I delete my win drive hibernation files without  a live disk?